# How to use nlasgest in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, return-value

I'm looking for the highest row of a dataframa, actually the idea is to pick the highest value and the index. I'm trying to use this code:

```
data_q11.nlargest(144,['1980','2010'])
```

where data_q11 is the dataframe,144 the number os rows in this df and range of columns.

Although the result is returning a empty list of 0 rows and x 31 columns.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Pls post a code example

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in Pandas for the index of the maximum value:

```
data_q11['col'].idxmax(axis=1)
```